# Getting correct perf version

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to run perf on my Ubuntu Precise box, which I recently upgraded to kernel 3.11.10-03111002 (manual install). The problem is that perf and kernel versions must match, and the requested version is not available in the repositories (linux-tools-VERSION package). I can only install up to v3.8.0.

What can I do? Kernel upgrade/downgrade is an option, but I'd rather get the correct perf version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get the sources of your 3.11.10-03111002 kernel
- Jump to it `cd ./linux-3.11.10-03111002/tools/perf`
- Type `make` and hit enter.

To run, type `./perf`

that's it.

For other options type `make help`

Comment: do you know where I could find the source for this kernel version? Googling for it only returns this page.

Comment: You can use also the vanilla kernel from [www.kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/). BTW: It mustn't be the same kernel version. AFAIS it is sufficient to have the same patch level.

Comment: It's ever easy with Linux :-(

Comment: Need dependencies.
Solution: `sudo apt-get -y install flex bison libdwarf-dev libelf-dev libpython-dev libunwind-dev`
util/PERF-VERSION-GEN: Syntax error: "elif" unexpected (expecting "then")
Solution: `git reset --hard` from another OS.
util/event.c:448:2: error: ‘readdir_r’ is deprecated
Solution: ???